# Any particular significance to the insects in episode 83 when Netero and one of the world leaders are having a discussion?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In *Hunter X Hunter* episode 83, when Netero received "orders" from one of the world leaders to exterminate the Ants, there were insects moving on the window facing the leader as well as the one beside Netero while they were talking. Since those insects were given significant "screen time", I thought they signified something that I hadn't figured out yet.

At first, I thought they could be connected to Ponzu (but the insects didn't look like bees), Ponzu's bees had already done their job anyways and why would one fly to meet a supposedly 'Muggle' president anyways? I've searched a bit online already but couldn't find anything. Is there anything here directly related to the story or is it just some metaphor/symbolic thing regarding how the Hunters were about to confront Insects?

[image: ladybug with the world leader]

[image: ladybug with Netero]

Comment: The insect on the association guy’s window gets smacked off, right? I sorta interpreted that as the association doesn’t care about insect life & Netero does. Could also be foreshadowing of things said by Netero later in the arc, about his swaying opinions. I don’t think there’s a clear answer for this question tho. It’s a subjective interpretation

Comment: @MackenzieMcClane Yeah, considering the way the guy tried to crush the insect, it looks like it symbolizes the leaders' disdain for the Ants and intention to exterminate them entirely. Netero was indifferent (or unaware?) to it though. Wonder what *that* means.